# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Typescript / Angular 6

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular6

I'm Implementing small chat application using socket.io gladly it's working fine. But my concern is when I got a new chat I need to assign it to string array to display in listview.

I have simply define array as **"messages: string[] = [];"** and pushed sample string on page load and it's working fine.But when I got new message from a socket **this.socket.on('newmessage', function (data)** method will fire and can read new message.those all things working correctly.

But When I push new string into my **"messages: string[] = [];"** array. I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' error.

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatbox',
  templateUrl: './chatbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatbox.component.css'],

})

export class ChatboxComponent implements OnInit {
  socket;
  messages: string[] = [];
  
  constructor() { this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000'); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeChatServer();
  }

  initializeChatServer() {
  
    this.messages.push( 'test 55');//This line works

    this.socket.on('newmessage', function (data) {
      console.log('message -> ' + data.nick + '>' + data.msg);     
      this.messages.push(data.msg); //Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    }); 
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Here we go again. Use an arrow function, not an anonymous function: `this.socket.on('newmessage', data => { ... })`

Comment: same comment, solve it using a fat arrow or .bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of synchronize call.I think it's not the standard way but it worked after I change like this..

```js
 initializeChatServer() {

    this.messages.push( 'test 55');
    var self = this;//assgin this to var variable
    this.socket.on('newmessage', data => {
      console.log('message -> ' + data.nick + '>' + data.msg);     
      self.messages.push(data.msg); 
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> this.messages.push(data.msg); //Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Because you have the wrong `this`. Arrow functions will fix that e.g. Change `this.socket.on('newmessage', function (data) {` to `this.socket.on('newmessage', (data) => {`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatbox',
  templateUrl: './chatbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatbox.component.css'],
})

export class ChatboxComponent implements OnInit {
  socket;
  messages: string[] = [];

  constructor() { this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000'); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeChatServer();
  }

  initializeChatServer() {

    this.messages.push( 'test 55');//This line works

    this.socket.on('newmessage', data => {
      console.log('message -> ' + data.nick + '>' + data.msg);     
      this.messages.push(data.msg); //Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    });

  }

}
```